# How do you save an image (passed in as a base64 encoded string) with Node.js

Tags: node.js, image, canvas, meteor, phantomjs

I created a HTML5 canvas with Phantom.js on my Meteor Application and i am trying to save the Canvas image on disk.

Problem: The saved image file appears to be corrupt (can't open it in an image viewer).

I got a base64 encoded PNG image from the HTML5 Canvas.toDataUrl method.
This is what my saved output from the Canvas.toDataUrl() function looks like:
  WzMyLDMyLDU4LDQ3LDEwOSwxMTEsMTAwLDExNywxMDgsMTAxLDExNSw0NywxMTksMTAxLDk4LDExMiw5NywxMDMsMTAxLDQ2LDEwNiwxMTUsNTgsNTAsNTYsNDksMTBd

This is my Save Routine:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(CanvasString)).toString('base64');
var fs = Meteor.npmRequire("fs");
var fullFileName = fileName + '.png';
fs.writeFileSync(fullFileName, buffer, "binary");
```

I can view the saved image as plaintext with a text editor like the output above.

Comment: It's base64 encoded, you have to decode it before writing to file. Maybe `fs.writeFileSync(fullFileName, buffer, "base64");` also works.

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps :

```
// our data URL string from canvas.toDataUrl();
var imageDataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,[...]";
// declare a regexp to match the non base64 first characters
var dataUrlRegExp = /^data:image\/\w+;base64,/;
// remove the "header" of the data URL via the regexp
var base64Data = imageDataUrl.replace(dataUrlRegExp, "");
// declare a binary buffer to hold decoded base64 data
var imageBuffer = new Buffer(base64Data, "base64");
// write the buffer to the local file system synchronously
fsWriteFileSync("/tmp/test.png", imageBuffer);
```

- Note : you probably don't want to use `fs.writeFileSync` to write on disk in Node.JS because it will block the entire Node event loop.

Instead wrap the call using `Meteor.wrapAsync` :

```
var fsWriteFileSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(fs.writeFile, fs);
```